# locatio.href pass variable

Tags: php, variables

is it possible to pass variable in PHP using the `onclick="location.href"`?

like the href do

```
echo "<a href='reply1.php?r_username=".$rows['comment']."&prod_id=".$row['prod_id']."'     class='reply_button'> REPLY </a>  ";
```

Comment: I think you're confusing: `location.href ` is used for redirection, while `<a href=...` tag is used to create a (clickable) link. It's not clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Use this example for your solution

```
   window.location.href = "myphpfile.php?one=" + one + "&two=" + two;
```

if you want ajax request:

```
    $.ajax({
       url: "myphpfile.php",
       method: 'get',
       data : {one:"one",two:"two"},
      success:function() {
      alert("hi to all");
      });
```